# Combine Publisher does not cancel when subscribed to on a background queue

Tags: swift, combine

I'm trying to take advantage of Combine's ability to `subscribe` to an upstream Publisher on a different queue but I'm finding that when I do, the upstream Publisher does not correctly get cancelled.

The documentation for [subscribe(on:options:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/subscribe(on:options:)) makes the following reference:

> Using subscribe(on:options:) also causes the upstream publisher to
> perform cancel() using the specified scheduler.

It's not entirely clear to me what this statement implies. In the example code below, I have a basic type `NameIterator` that conforms to `Sequence` and `IteratorProtocol`. It's just simulating a custom iterator that might take a long time to fetch elements.

Combine adds a `.publisher` property to `Sequence`. If you subscribe to that publisher in a single thread, then any cancellation events are correctly propagated up to the root publisher and iteration stops.

However, if you call `subscribe(on:)`, then the cancellation event does not reach the root publisher until it has exhausted calls to the iterator. Note that `sink` is correctly called in both cases, but the iterator continues to get called even though no values are being pushed down the pipeline.

This causes a problem if the iterator is expensive and contains a large number of items, like traversing a filesystem. Is there a way to correctly cancel the upstream publisher? Or perhaps I'm incorrectly configuring the chain of Publishers.

**Sample Iterator:**

```
struct NameIterator: Sequence, IteratorProtocol {

  private let names = ["Alpha", "Beta", "Charlie", "Delta"]
  private var index = 0

  mutating func next() -> String? {
    guard index < names.endIndex else {
      return nil
    }

    // Simulate an expensive iterator.
    sleep(1)
    
    defer { index = names.index(after: index) }
    print("NameIterator.next() called with \(names[index])")
    return names[index]
  }
}
```

**Correctly Cancelled:**

```
let cancellable = NameIterator().publisher
  .first()
  .sink { print("Sink: \($0)") }

// Outputs:

NameIterator.next() called with Alpha
NameIterator.next() called with Beta
Sink: Alpha
```

**Incorrectly Cancelled:**

```
let cancellable = NameIterator().publisher
  .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue(label: "BackgroundQueue"))
  .first()
  .sink { print("Sink: \($0)") }

// Outputs: 

NameIterator.next() called with Alpha
NameIterator.next() called with Beta
Sink: Alpha
NameIterator.next() called with Charlie  // This call was unexpected.
NameIterator.next() called with Delta    // This call was unexpected.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quote from the documentation is not a statement about cancellation, it's a statement about threading. It says: if you subscribe on a certain queue, then that is the queue that will be used when/if the time comes for the cancellation message to be sent up the pipeline.

By choosing to subscribe on a specified queue, you are explicitly saying: when the time comes to cancel, queue that call. So, as with any action on a queue, we now have no idea when that will actually happen. The claim that "this call should not have happened" is thus wrong; there is no "should have" in the story. On the contrary, any expectation as to when cancellation would percolate up to the publisher is exactly what you gave up when you subscribed on the queue.

(Observe, by the way, that the Completion arrives *down* the pipeline in good order at the expected moment — that is, the sink gets the Alpha value followed immediately by the `.finished` Completion. It is only the *publisher* that you have given all this extra leeway to.)

Comment: Thanks for the insight. If a cancellation request is enqueued on the queue given to `subscribe(on:)`, and the cancellation is not delivered until after `Sequence.publisher` has finished, then that significantly limits how `subscribe(on:)` can be used. IMHO, the use of `subscribe(on:)` is very beneficial for long running (or slow) Publishers, which are the very ones I want to terminate as soon as possible. I can work around this by using `handleEvents` and manually cancelling the iterator, but that didn't seem right. Is there another way to force an upstream Publisher to cancel?

Comment: @kennyc, how's what you're asking different from the normal behavior of publishers, which is that a subscription can be cancelled by the downstream, which the upstream publishers receive and act on?

Comment: In the example above, the upstream `Sequence.publisher` does not act upon the downstream cancellation until after iterating through the entire `Sequence`. The downstream Publishers stop being called as expected, but the upstream one, which is on a different queue, continues to do work it does not need to be doing because no downstream Publishers are subscribed anymore. In my app, the upstream Publisher is recursively traversing the contents of a directory. I want it to stop traversing immediately after a downstream Publisher cancels the pipeline.